# Create android web view which supports flash

Tags: java, android, flash, android-webview

I have a flash web game, which is developed for desktop browsers and I want to run the same in android. But android web view won't support flash. Is there any way to make it run? Because there are browsers (ie Puffin) which support flash so I'm curious to know how that work.

Comment: Not webView... Puffin makers could read about **SWF format specifications** and write a parser / decoder. PS: When you use the Flash program to compile the AS3 code into an app, there's many choices... compile for browser plugin (swf), or compile for HTML5 (JS files), or compile for Android (apk) etc.. Once you make as one format it cannot be converted. If you have the original code try exporting as HTML5 game and run in webView... For without code, I'll test within next 24hrs if its possible to compile AS3 to APK while having a game SWF **embedded as graphic asset** inside the generated app.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Adobe (the makers of Flash) pulled support for Flash on Android years ago.  You really shouldn't be coding anything new in Flash-  the security on Flash is horrible, every major desktop browser is turning Flash off by default.  Within the next year or so they'll probably stop supporting it at all.  This isn't something Adobe could fix even if they wanted to (and they don't, they no longer make new versions)- its insecure in its design.

If some particular browser is supporting flash, they wrote the support 100% by themselves.  Expect it to be buggy and even less secure than normal Flash.

Comment: Is every major desktop still running Java? It was more insecure than Flash!! Not even creators like Sun / Oracle could fix it.. Nowadays both Flash and Java are used to compile APK files for Android. They died on the web, were reborn as mobile native code. PS: Whats up with browsers failing to securely handle **compiled code** apps yet O.S can do it? Take any **.exe** compiled by Java, C# or Flash. Runs fine on Windows but same code via plugins of Java, Silverlight or Flash and result just stresses the browser. Blame happens. All three plugins are now dead or dying. Silly world...